# Why can't I add members an imported declaration?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to add a constructor to an imported declaration. According to [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/deep-dive.html) this should work. (Chapter `Adding using an interface`)

Here is my code:

```
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb';

interface ObjectID {
  new(b: Buffer): ObjectID;
}
```

I get the following error message:

> Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'ObjectID'at line 2 col 10

As a workaround I renamed the interface and do a type assertion to any and then to my interface. This is good enough since I only need it in one place but still I'm wondering why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're importing *and* declaring locally, so the error is accurate. For imported code you should probably create a [declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) instead.

But in this case you don't seem to need to create a declaration for mongodb. [Definition files already exist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/mongodb). You can just do

```
npm install @types/mongodb --save-dev
```

So you'll get everything declared for you. [Here's the constructor in question](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/mongodb/index.d.ts#L407).

Comment: I'm actually already using that type definition (sorry, should have stated explicitly). The constructor you linked to only accepts string and number, which is correct according to the API docs. But there is also the undocumented possibility to pass a buffer. That's what I wanted to add to the existing declaration.